# It doesn't return true when I am comparing my csrf token to the session token

Tags: php, forms, session

I am trying use a random token and store this as a session, then placing this in a hidden input text, which is sent to my processing page. If both the token are matched, then the form will be processed but when echoing out both of the tokens, they do match but on a live server, it is not matching....

I have tried to use both the !== and the != sign but even though that both tokens are the same, it still can't match them..

I have placed this code in my main form section. This is part of my code because my form is a bit too long

```
$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

<br></br>
         <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>


This is part of my processing form:

 $csrf = strip_tags($_POST['csrf']);



      // information from memberships' table

       $subscriptionplan = strip_tags($_POST['subscriptionplan']);

       $pricing_level1 = strip_tags($_POST['pricing_level1']);
       $pricing_level2 = strip_tags($_POST['pricing_level2']);
       $pricing_level3 = strip_tags($_POST['pricing_level3']);

       // referral information

       $referral = strip_tags($_POST['referral']);


       if(hash_equals($csrf, $_SESSION['token'])) {

                                              header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=wrongtoken");
                                              exit();
                                            } else {
```

Comment: This looks like you generate a _new_ session token for each request. So different ones for the form generating and the form processing request.

Comment: I might be confused here but maybe someone could just assist me here... This line of code: if(hash_equals($csrf, $_SESSION['token'])) {

Comment: are we checking to see if they matched? and if so, I think I have just redirected the user if they do matched!

Comment: silly me! Should I have used... if(!hash_equals($csrf, $_SESSION['token']){}

Comment: which of the following should I use to randomly generate a string? base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));

Comment: or bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

Comment: and why is it better to use if (hash_equals)?

Comment: I have set the form to the post variable... so which is better/ openssl or bin2hex?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you forgot to set your form submission type to `post`. The default submission type of any HTML form, if not set, is `get`, so either set it to `post`, or assign the values to variables from `$_GET[...]` super global, not `$_POST[...]`.